# Lock keys panel indicator for MATE Desktop. Num Lock indicator stays on

Tags: mate, numlock, tweak

I have activated the Mate Tweak for "Enable Keyboard LED" which works for CapsLk but NumLk stays on all the time after first activation. Any suggestions for curing this annoyance would be much appreciated. I have a Thinkpad X201 running Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?